# Trouble getting Rails API to display 'show' record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jbuilder

I have a rails 5.2 API.  I'm able to display the list of 'blogs' at `site.com/blogs.json` but when I try to show an individual blog at `site.com/blogs/blog-1.json` I get a 500 server error.

**blogs_controller.rb**

```
  def show
    @blog.punch(request)
    @meta_title = meta_title @blog.title

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.json 
    end
  end
```

I'm using `jbuilder` in the Rails view directory, and it's here I suspect I have something wrong, but can't see what.

**_blog.json.jbuilder**

```
json.array! @blogs, :id, :title, :text, :created_at, :updated_at, :url 
json.url blog_url(blog, format: :json)
```

**index.json.jbuilder**

```
json.array! @blogs
```

**show.json.jbuilder**

```
json.partial! "blogs/blog", blog: @blog
```

Comment: Just a guess, but `blogs/1.json`? What's your `rake routes` output?

Comment: Also, what is the error in the console?